# Grant permissions/change owner to a user

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a a two folders `/opt/tom` and `/opt/test/` that has the following permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Apr  2 16:23 tom
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Apr  2 16:16 test
```

how can I grant the permission to a user called `john` so that it looks like this?

```
drwxr-sr-x 3 john root 4096 Dec  5 13:22 tom
drwxrwxrwx 3 john root 4096 Apr  1 16:45 test
```

Comment: In your example, you're granting permission to a user, not a group.

Comment: @Barmar, just changed

Comment: Updated my answer to fit your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change a user, you use (as root or with `sudo`):

```
chown john tom test
```

To set the rights:

```
chmod 777 /opt/test
chmod 2755 /opt/tom
```

(2 will set SGID bit)

You can always add `-R` switch, so it will be a recursive change. It's worth adding, that usually setting SUID/SGID bits for a directory makes new files created in this directory inherit this options.

Comment: Glad to help :) If you like the answer, you can always upvote it ;-)